# How to select a column for a where statement based on another column value in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, where-in

I'm currently beginning a project for which i need to do some data management in SQL.

I want to check wether i have enough history for an individual to be included in the analysis
I extracted data in a table that contains a column 'index_date' (date datatype) that correspond to the index date and multiple columns 'info_AAAA' that I use to state whether the individual figures on the database the year AAAA

i want to select only patients that figures in the database at least for the year AAAA, AAAA-1 and AAAA-2

But as I'm an absolute beginner in sql i can't figure how to do this

Comment: Please [edit] the question and provide a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your table and sample data; **YOUR** attempt at a solution to the problem; the issues/errors with your solution; and the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a column 'index_date' in my dataset that correspond to the index date

That's kind of self-descriptive, but - what is "index date"? What does it represent? Is it relevant for this case?

---

> and **multiple** columns 'presence_AAAA' stating wether the individual figures on the database the year AAAA

Now that sounds scary! Are you saying that table actually looks like this?

```
Name    Presence_2021   Presence_2022   Presence_2023
-----   -------------   -------------   -------------
Scott   yes             yes             no
```

If so, you're doing it wrong. Table should have only one `presence_year` column, e.g.

```
Name    Presence_year   Present
-----   -------------   -------
Scott   2021            yes
Scott   2022            yes
Scott   2023            no
```

because - what will you do next year? Add yet another column and modify **ALL** queries you wrote so far in order to include newly added column? And then repeat it the next year, and the year after, and ...? That's insane, don't do that.

---

Anyway: 3 years back can be calculated; question is what you really have in that table.

If it were *my* table, you'd e.g.

```
select *
from that_table
where presence_year >= extract(year from sysdate) - 2
```

If you want to relate it to `index_date` (presuming that it is a `DATE` datatype column), you'd

```
select *
from that_table
where index_date >= add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy'), -2 * 12)
```

Other options are also possible; again, depending on what you really have.

Comment: Sorry i did not know how to formulate my question correctly: 
I'm working on a preexisting database, and yes it is structured as "presence_2020",  "presence_2021" etc etc (they do not contain only the presence information but i wanted to simplify, i use them as an indicator because they are empty "." when the individual was not in the database)
yes index_date is a date datatype column
I extracted these information to create a table

I really don't know how to procede so I cannot really give examples of what I did try I thought of pivoting the table but I'm not sure of how to do that

Answer (score 0):

> I want to check whether I have enough history for an individual to be included in the analysis. I have a column `index_date` in my dataset that correspond to the index date and multiple columns `presence_AAAA` stating whether the individual figures on the database the year AAAA.

Let us assume you have a table containing the individual data-points:

```sql
CREATE TABLE patient_data (
  patient_id NUMBER,
  index_date DATE,
  some_data  VARCHAR2(100),
  other_data VARCHAR2(100)
);
```

Then you can generate your history using conditional aggregation in a view:

```sql
CREATE VIEW patient_year_data (patient_id, presence_2022, presence_2023, presence_2024) AS
SELECT patient_id,
       CASE
       WHEN COUNT(
              CASE
              WHEN index_date >= DATE '2022-01-01' AND index_date < DATE '2023-01-01'
              THEN 1
              END
            ) > 0
       THEN 'Yes'
       ELSE 'No'
       END,
       CASE
       WHEN COUNT(
              CASE
              WHEN index_date >= DATE '2023-01-01' AND index_date < DATE '2024-01-01'
              THEN 1
              END
            ) > 0
       THEN 'Yes'
       ELSE 'No'
       END,
       CASE
       WHEN COUNT(
              CASE
              WHEN index_date >= DATE '2024-01-01' AND index_date < DATE '2025-01-01'
              THEN 1
              END
            ) > 0
       THEN 'Yes'
       ELSE 'No'
       END
FROM   patient_data
WHERE  index_date >= DATE '2022-01-01'
AND    index_date <  DATE '2025-01-01'
GROUP BY patient_id
```

> I want to select only patients that figures in the database at least for the year AAAA, AAAA-1 and AAAA-2

Then you can use:

```sql
SELECT patient_id
FROM   patient_year_data
WHERE  presence_2024 = 'Yes'
AND    presence_2023 = 'Yes'
AND    presence_2022 = 'Yes'
```

However, you don't need the view and could directly use the underlying table:

```sql
SELECT patient_id
FROM   patient_data
GROUP BY patient_id
HAVING  COUNT(
          CASE
          WHEN index_date >= DATE '2022-01-01' AND index_date < DATE '2023-01-01'
          THEN 1
          END
        ) > 0
AND     COUNT(
          CASE
          WHEN index_date >= DATE '2023-01-01' AND index_date < DATE '2024-01-01'
          THEN 1
          END
        ) > 0
AND     COUNT(
          CASE
          WHEN index_date >= DATE '2024-01-01' AND index_date < DATE '2025-01-01'
          THEN 1
          END
        ) > 0
```